# How can I make my PC monitor the login monitor in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, login-screen

I have a TV attached to the HDMI port and my monitor attached to the DVI port.  When I booted up in 16.04 moving the mouse to one side of the screen or the other would make the login prompt move from one screen to the other.  Now I've "upgraded" to 18.04 the login prompt only appears on the TV screen.   Changing the TV screen input to PC isn't going to go down very well if someone is watching the TV at the time...

When I configure the displays in settings after logging in the TV is display 1 and the monitor is display 2, if that's relevant.

Comment: It's a pain, the solution that works for me is to detach the DVI monitor. Yeah, probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did the first time but, you're right, it's not what I'm looking for...